# Is it possible to store a Object's reference in H2?

Tags: java, reference, h2

I need to store java object in H2 database so that I can call the object's method in a easy way.

I read [data type](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#identity_type) of H2. The only way I can store an java Object is to use type "OTHER Type". 
However this data type employs serialization and deserialization. If I store a very large object, it means it gonna take much time and memory to do serialization stuff.

I just want to **refer the object**. Is there anyway to achieve it?

If H2 cannot achieve it, is there any other in memory database can achieve it?

Comment: Short answer, no.  You can't get the memory location of object, nor should you be trying to store it, as it will change between executions of the program

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you mad, how should I solve this situation? I can add an id for each object can maintain a Map<id,object>, though it is such an ugly solution.

Comment: Implement a flyweight without H2.

Comment: > is there any other in memory database can achieve it? -
Yes, ConcurrentHashMap